# facebook og:image - correct on URL Linter but not working on my site

Tags: facebook, iis, firewall

unfortunately i am un able to share any URLS with you guys but hoepfully someone has come accross this before

ok so when i use the Linter to check my page everythign is perfect and is working as exspected.

when i share what i want to share on my website its ignoring the og:image

we have recently moved servers and it worked perfect on the old server but the new server is not showing the correct OG image

i still have access to the old server and tested it again today (both old and new identical code) and it still working correct

does anyone know of any IIS settings or Firewall settings what would stop facebook pulling in the correct og:image when i sahre it but work on the linter?

Odd

Comment: Did you change the image itself but use the same URL? If so, does it work when you change the image URL?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had an answer for you as I am going through the same ordain. Linter sees the correct image but facebook does not uses this image when sharing. It does it uses the right image when using the like button, weird.

Best input I can give you it is to wait for facebook to fix this problem as it sounds to me that they are the ones responsibles for this bug.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for leaving this one un answered.

it seemed to correct itself, we accessed the site from another IP and then it started to work fine in the office, strange indeed